# Why there isn't a uniqueness theorem for $n$th order $m$ variable ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So the uniqueness theorem I found online looked mostly like this. [uniqueness theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-existence-uniqueness-of-solutions-to-higher-order-linear).

But why isn't there an uniqueness theorem for $n$th order, $m$(multi) variable ODE?
i.e. 
$$\frac{d^n y}{d t^n}+ \frac{d^n y}{d x^n}+...+\frac{d^n y}{d v^n}+... =f(t,x,...,u,v)$$

Comment: This not an ODE, but a PDE. I am not quite sure what the question is. There is no uniqueness theorem, because there is no uniqueness :) Actually the solution space can be infinite-dimensional (consider for example the Laplace-equation).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven : As written, those are [total derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#Example:_Differentiation_with_direct_dependencies), not [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).  So this is a [total differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_differential_equation), not a PDE.

Comment: @EricTowers I do not quite agree with you. I do not see any explicite dependence of the variables on each other.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven : The absence of explicit dependence relationships is overwhelmingly common in ODEs and TDEs.  The implicit dependence relationships in both cases are that any written total derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}b}$ establishes that $b$ is an independent variable and $a$ depends on $b$.  The relations you do not see are implicit in the equation.  (It's convention.  I'm not saying it's a good way to do this.)

Comment: @EricTowers I was not aware of that. In fact not even of the term TDE. I thought the OP just liked $d$ better than $\partial$ :)